# Find and Copy content of cells with a specific text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for an Excel formula that does the next:

- The cell A2 must find in the cells from C2 to E2 those containing the number "1".
- Then, it must remove the space and number and copy it to A2.
- If two or more cells in the range C2:E2 contain "1", both chunks of texts appear in A2.
- If none of the cells in the range C2:E2 contain "1", the result is 0.

Expected result:
[image: THIS IS THE RESULT I AM TRYING TO GET]

Comment: Sounds like a fairly complex task to do, in a VBA macro. Have you worked with VBA Excel macros?

Comment: No, I thought it would be possible with a formula!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formulas are pretty big, but they work:

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(C2,1)="1",RIGHT(D2,1)="1",RIGHT(E2,1)="1"),TEXTJOIN("/",1,IF(RIGHT(C2,1)="1",LEFT(C2,2),""),IF(RIGHT(D2,1)="1",LEFT(D2,2),""),IF(RIGHT(E2,1)="1",LEFT(E2,2),"")),0)
```

Slightly shorter **array formula** version:

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(C2:E2,1)="1"),TEXTJOIN("/",1,IF(RIGHT(C2,1)="1",LEFT(C2,2),""),IF(RIGHT(D2,1)="1",LEFT(D2,2),""),IF(RIGHT(E2,1)="1",LEFT(E2,2),"")),0)
```

Even longer version of regular formula when `TEXTJOIN` is not available:

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(C2,1)="1",RIGHT(D2,1)="1",RIGHT(E2,1)="1"),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(IF(RIGHT(C2,1)="1",LEFT(C2,2),"") &" "& IF(RIGHT(D2,1)="1",LEFT(D2,2),"") &" "& IF(RIGHT(E2,1)="1",LEFT(IE2,2),""))," ","/"),0)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much.